# android webview with video.js

Tags: android, webview

I built a website that uses Video.JS as a player now I make an apk from that web using Android web view, but I can't play videos.

I understand that there is the problem with video tag on android web view.

Comment: hey, did you managed the issue with video.js not playing on webview? perfectly works in mobile Chrome in my case, but shows blank black screen on webview.